# Visual studio 2010 error: There was an error downloading metadata from the address

Tags: visual-studio-2010, metadata, stdio

I am trying to add a service reference to my WEBModel.

However, when I am trying to search my reference from the Service, I am getting the error message:

```
There was an error downloading metadata from the address. Please verify that you have
entered a valid address.
```

and moreover, when I just want to open my local host page, I am getting:

---

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required
to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify
your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: An error occurred loading a configuration file: Failed to start
monitoring changes to
'\\psf\home\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TVProject(2)\TVProject\SL'.

Source Error: 


[No relevant source lines]


Source File:
\\psf\home\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TVProject(2)\TVProject\SL\web.config
```

---

I was searching to resolve this problems, but I didn't find anything relevant for my case. (I changed webConfig file and created new project.)

Does anybody know how to solve this error?